# Get phone (GSM) signal strength without use of private API

Tags: ios, swift, gsm

I am developing an iOS app in swift and need to know the GSM signal strength. I am aware that this can be done with private API's like CoreTelephony's `CTGetSignalStrength`, but as my app has to go in the app store, I can't use private API's.

Does any one know of a way to check the signal strength without the use of private API's?

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no public API available for doing this. If you'd rather not risk using the private APIs and absolutely must have this, you're best bet is to use a combination of the Reachability framework alongside benchmarking downloads yourself. Unfortunately, the only thing you can really do is open up a socket or something at a consistent basis and ping data back and forth. You'll have to gage the speed yourself and determine signal strength that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea if you are worried about data transfer speed via cellular. Place some file on server (can be image) and download it. Measure time before and after it has been downloaded. Can repeat. If you know the download time for good connection, you can decide what time is not ok.

You can also request something from server few times to get headers back and thus determine something similar to ping in miliseconds.

```
func evaluateDownloadTime() -> Double 
{
    let start = NSDate(); // Start time

    // Your Download process to measure    

    let end = NSDate();   // End time
    let timeInterval: Double = end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start); 
    // Difference in seconds (double). You may need miliseconds.

    return timeInterval
}
print("Time measured: \(evaluateTime()) seconds");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what i am looking for is a way to know if i will be able to send a text message or not :). Do you know of any way of doing this?

Comment: There is a Reachability framework that can detect if there is a cellular network connection or not. Take a look if it's something you are looking for: [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability--mobile-18299)